# JavaScript pass new array in argument

Tags: javascript, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Is there a way (like we have in C# generics/linq list.take...) that can take a range of elements of an array in the argument while calling a function, without having to create a new array?

```
//a simple array with some elements
myArray; 
//just to show what I mean...pass the first five elemtns of array to the function
doSomethingWithArray(myArray[0,4]); 


function doSomethingWithArray(items) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
doSomethingWithArray(myArray.slice(0, 4))
```

Slice takes `start` and `end` parameters and returns a *shallow copy* of the items in the array that fall within that range. If you want to mutate the array you can consider [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Note that the `end` index is *non-inclusive*, i.e. `myArray.slice(0,4)`, in the example, returns only elements in the range `[0 .. 3]`.